# Quantifying Poincare map

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

I have a dynamical system which goes from chaos to ordered state (quasiperiodic state to be precise). I have represented this transition via a Poincare map. See the attached figures.
[image]
Now, my question: Is there any way of quantifying this different phases from these graphs? Like a statistical or geometrical parameter to recognize different patterns each graph?

Comment: Speaking about the last picture: can you show how does the truncated trajectory of Poincare map look like? I mean, you have, for example, 10000 points in trajectory, but how do last 2-3K points look like on the diagram? Because to me the last picture looks more like the quasiperiodic dynamic than periodic.

Comment: @Evgeny: Yeah. you are right. It is quasi-periodic.

Comment: I know that there is a quite traditional approach when you wait until trajectory approaches attractor and then compute Largest Lyapunov Exponent (LLE) along it. However, quasiperiodic dynamics corresponds to zero LLE in theory and very small LLE in practice. Does this approach suit your problem?

Comment: Would you please show us the system equations?